# Download large files from asmx in .NET 2.0

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, .net-2.0, asmx

We have a client which is written in **.NET 2.0** (and it can not be changed). This client communicates with web service (no WCF, just plain asmx) written in .NET 4.0.
Now we need to donload rather large files (**200 MB**) from the web service. There can be approx. 1000 clients connected at the same time and downloading. The current implementation of the ws method is **very naive**. The whole file (which si XML by the way) is read in memory as string and the **string is returned**.

Slightly better approach would be to read it as **byte array** as suggested [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13339/File-Download-using-Web-Service) :
but I think it is still wrong approach. The large file will be still in the memory (multiplied by base64 etc.)

The best way would be to use **streaming**. I know that the WCF is capable of streaming (e.g. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP?msg=4187161#xx4187161xx)), but the WCF is probably not possible for us, as the client (.NET 2,0) would have to somehow use capability of the .NET 3.0 (by using its assemblies from WCF), which could be nasty.

Is there another possibility, how to ensure that server will be capable to server so many downloads of such big files?

Comment: ASMX doesn't do streaming. It is very bad at memory usage. His is one of the reasons it was replaced by WCF. You're not going to get modern features from ancient software. Period.

Comment: If the task at hand was easy, I would not ask here at SO. I know that the ASMX is ancient, but due to some bussines restriction we can not upgrade to WCF as I mentioned in the post. Alkso, the question was "Is there another possibility, how to ensure that server will be capable to server so many downloads of such big files?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, may be this posts will be helpful (I did not tested them, but looks like helpful):

[Web services and large content in .NET 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yassers/archive/2004/11/10/255212.aspx)

[How to: Stream Large Amounts of Data from a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528818.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for interesting links (+1). We will try what is proposed in the articles and get back here with updates.

Comment: So in the end we implemented quite succesfully the approach from this article the first article you mentioned: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yassers/archive/2004/11/10/255212.aspx